# I want to print each iteration of this loop untill it hits 6, nd then want to reset the process (I am a total newbie)

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, for-loop

[Hello, basically what I want is that, when I press the floating button it should iterate untill number 6. After it reaches 6 I want the whole loop or this counteer to reset and again iterate to 6. I am a complete newbie, please help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpMJr.jpg)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: idcard(),
    ));

class idcard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<idcard> createState() => _idcardState();
}

class _idcardState extends State<idcard> {
  int ballNumber = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            for (ballNumber = 0; ballNumber <= 5; ballNumber += 1);
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[800],
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[800],
        title: Text("Ball Counter"),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Ball number",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text("$ballNumber",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 90, color: Colors.yellow[800])),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, i slowed value reset for 1 second because if i don't add this you will see always 0 .

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: idcard(),
        ));
    
    class idcard extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<idcard> createState() => _idcardState();
    }
    
    class _idcardState extends State<idcard> {
      int ballNumber = 0;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                for (ballNumber = 0; ballNumber <= 5; ballNumber += 1);
               
              });
              
               Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:1),(){
                  setState((){
                    ballNumber=0;
                  });
                });
            },
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[800],
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[800],
            title: Text("Ball Counter"),
            centerTitle: true,
            elevation: 0.0,
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Ball number",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text("$ballNumber",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 90, color: Colors.yellow[800])),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```